# How do I select certain objects under $(this) in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying really hard to learn how to loop through rows in a jQuery dataTable, not doing too terribly well.

My table id is "partslist". So:

```
    $("#partslist tr").each(function() {
        $($(this) + " td").each(function() {
            alert($(this).text());
        })
    })
```

You can see that the:

$($(this) + " td").each ...

is a big fat failure. I want to loop through the columns in each row. It's funny, with all those examples on the dataTables website, I can't find a single one that would let me get the data from the table easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this:

```
$("#partslist tr").each(function() {
        $(this).find("td").each(function() {
            alert($(this).text());
        })
    })
```

which finds all of the td's in selection of tr's

or this

```
$("#partslist tr").each(function() {
        $("td",$(this)).each(function() {
            alert($(this).text());
        })
    })
```

which finds all the td's using the selection of tr's as the scope or "context"

These both accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#partslist tr").each(function() {
    $("td", this).each(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another place to manipulate data inside of jQuery DataTables is within the fnRowCallback. This is an initialization parameter that provides the ideal place to get data and provide updates on a row-by-row basis. Also, since the internal rendering functions are already creating and caching certain objects, it's more efficient.

There are of course reasons to want the data AFTER it has been rendered, but your question doesn't indicate your use case. Here's a sample of manipulating the row right before the node gets appended to the DOM.

Here's a fake example. Imagine that in my data being returned (a 2D object, so I access it by index not by name) my second column contains a string representing the condition of a part. For simplicity, there are two options: New or Remanufactured. I'm actually passing a short-form string, though, so I want to convert it to a full word before displaying it:

```js
var oTable = $('#partslist').dataTable({
// ...other initialization parameters can go in here, too...
  fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData) {
    var condition = aData[1]; // second column of the data object if it's a 2D object
    var conditionFull = "New"; // by default, parts are in new condition
    if (condition == "reman") {
      conditionFull = "Remanufactured";
    }
    $('td:eq(1)', nRow).text(conditionFull); // use jQuery to select the second VISIBLE (HTML) column and update the text     
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your thorough answer. I have other use cases where this will come in handy!

Answer (score 0):

You could do `$(this).children('td').each...`, or just `$(this + ' td').each...` . I *think* either one will work, though I didn't test either.